# Thymeleaf could not parse as expression - summernote editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf, summernote

I want use summernote editor with thymeleaf. Accordign to summernote specification I have to use this JavaScript code:

```
<div th:value="$('#summernote').summernote('code')" ...
```

Unfortunately I receive thymeleaf exception:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "$('#summernote').summernote('code')"
```

Comment: Note sure about summernote, but for thymeleaf, your `th:value` should appear within the div tag

Comment: Correct, it should and it is. Thanks.